# Span Background Color set with javascript not printed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have the following code that sets a legend for a graph built with Morris Js:

```
grafico1.options.data.forEach(function(label, i) {
  var legendItem = $('<span></span></br>').text( label['label'] + " ( " +label['value'] + " )" ).prepend('<br><span>&nbsp;</span>');
  legendItem.find('span')
    .css('background-color', grafico1.options.colors[i])
    .css('width', '20px')
    .css('display', 'inline-block')
    .css('margin-right', '15px')
    .css('float','left');
  $('#legend').append(legendItem).css('text-align','left').css('font-size','15px')
});
```

The graph is the following:

[image: Graph on the web page before printing]

But when I want to print the graphs all the background colors of the `<span>` elements they disappear like in this picture:

[image: Legend without colors on printing]

I've already tried to include `body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }` in my css and to set Background Colors on printing but nothing seems to work.
It's not just a Chrome problem, I've tried with many other browsers.
I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: In your printer settings have you enabled/disabled background-colour printing as an ink-saving measure? Sometimes it's set by default. The easiest way to compensate, I suspect, is to set the text colour (with the `color` CSS property) in the `@media print` stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The colors of the background are set dynamically with javascript. How can i solve that in the media print stylesheet?

Comment: If the printer is set to ignore background-colours - as mine will always be - you can't solve that with JavaScript. But instead of using the `background-color` instead use the `color` property.

Comment: Unfortunately the element is of the type <span>, it does not have color property, only background color, or Am I wrong?

Comment: Every element that can contain text has a `color` property.

Answer (score 1):

For those (like me) stumbling upon this thread because they can't get their span background color to print in Firefox.

What worked for me was setting the following css in my span class:

```
print-color-adjust: exact;
```

You'll need to add

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

for Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i use bootstrap as external css. They have a `background: transparent` on the `@media print{}` part of the css. Just remove that line and the problem is solved!